# How to generate all possible combinations of a forgotten password

Tags: passwords, brute-force, dictionary

I have forgotten my password but I know the words used in the password. I remember the password was something like `MyPassport@1.82TB`.

Is there any software that can produce all combinations like replacing "M" with "m" or "1" with "!", something like that?

Comment: John the Ripper can help you with that...

Comment: A basic script can create the list for you, too.

Comment: Hashcat if I remember well my old days?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [rule based attack](https://www.4armed.com/blog/hashcat-rule-based-attack/).  Password cracking tools such as [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) and [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) can be used to crack passwords in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [mentalist](https://github.com/sc0tfree/mentalist), it generates custom word lists based on your parameters, it also has a GUI to make things easier as well. You can proceed to crack the password with the custom generated word list using password crackers like [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) and [John The Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) like other users have mentioned above.